# Threading not running as a background/parallel task

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to use a location tracking function as a background task, so that I can tag locations to other functions. Essentially, I want to track locations then have a menu of other functions that I can start at a desired location (take an image, mark location, machine learning functions, etc). From what I can tell, threading appears to be the way to go.

So I created:

```
# Location Stuff
def trackLocation():
    
    # Global vars of x/y
    global currentX
    global currentY
    xList =[]
    yList = []
    while True:
    
        test = robot.get_frame_tree_snapshot()
        transform = bosdyn.client.frame_helpers.get_vision_tform_body(test)
        xT = transform.transform_point(0, 0, 0)
        #print(xT)
        x, y, z = xT
        xList.append(x)
        yList.append(y)
        
        currentX = x
        currentY = y
        print(currentX, currentY)

        time.sleep(2.0)
```

Which as an individual function, works great. Then I tried to create a test menu like so:

```
def threadTest():
    choice = '0'
    while choice == '0':
        
        choice = input("Enter number of selection: ")
            
        if choice == '1':
            print("please work", currentX, currentY)
            choice == '0'
```

Following [this](https://superfastpython.com/daemon-threads-in-python/), I tried to create a daemon thread as a background thread as that site seemed to be point this direction for background tasks and had a similar to what I was example.

```
t = threading.Thread(target=trackLocation(), daemon=True, args=())
t.start()
threadTest()
```

However, no matter what I do, it never seems to break the while loop inside the original function. It acts EXACTLY like it would if it was a regular function. I have tried several different variations of thread options (non-daemon, creating other function as thread, others too) but never breaks that loop. I just want that tracking in the background while I do other stuff.

I even went as far to create a simpler file to test variations of main and running in cmd. No luck.

```
import time
import threading
import sys


def threadTest():
    
    global cx
    global cy
    x = 1
    y = 2
    while True:
        x += 1
        y += 1
        
        #print(x, y)
        time.sleep(2.0)
    
def threadChoice():
    choice = '0'
    while choice == '0':
        
        choice = input("Enter number of selection: ")
            
        if choice == '1':
            print("please work", cx, cy)
    

def main(argv):
    
    t = threading.Thread(target=threadTest(), args = ())
    t.start()
    threadChoice()
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not main(sys.argv[1:]):
        sys.exit(1)
```

What am I missing here? I want to track location (or addition in sample) in background and run other functions while it is going and grab location information as needed.

Comment: What you're missing is, `target=threadTest()` _calls_ the `threadTest` function, and then it uses whatever is returned by `threadTest` as the target of the new thread. Your `threadTest` returns `None`, and if you create a new thread using `None` for the target, then the new thread does nothing when you `start()` it.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. So, I need a return value?

Comment: `target=threadTest()` --> `target=threadTest`